# php regex extract matches where tag contain a specific word

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have the following string:

```
<product><name>Tea</name><price>12</price></product>
<product><name>black coffee</name><price>23</price></product>
<product><name>cheap black-coffee</name><price>44</price></product>
```

I would like to grab all products where "coffee" or "coffee black" occurs.

I tried with the following code:

```
preg_match_all('/<product>(.*?)(black coffee|black-coffee)(.*?)<\/product>/is', $string, $result);
```

But that code merges two of the products in the array. As you can tell, I am not at all familiar with regex.

Comment: Don't use regex for this; you will only create headaches for yourself. Use a parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a negative lookahead assertion instead of `.*?` because `.*?` will also match `<product>` or `</product>` tags.

```
<product>((?:(?!<\/?product).)*?)(black coffee|black-coffee)((?:(?!<\/?product).)*?)<\/product>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nL2dV4/1)

```
$re = "/<product>(?:(?:(?!<\\/?product).)*?)(?:black coffee|black-coffee)(?:(?:(?!<\\/?product).)*?)<\\/product>/is";
$str = "<product><name>Tea</name><price>12</price></product>\n<product><name>black coffee</name><price>23</price></product>\n<product><name>cheap black-coffee</name><price>44</price></product>";
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0])
```

Comment: turn all the capturing groups to non-capturing groups in-order to avoid unnecessary capture https://regex101.com/r/nL2dV4/2